# CSS Issue - display none/ display block showing weird behaviour

Tags: html, css, angularjs, user-interface, css-selectors

I am really confused here.. There is an accordion which renders child elements and sub child elements through angular js ng repeat. one of the child and sub child accordion section works fine with display none and display block on hover but when dragged to the below sections the hover fails and automatically closes the whole parent elements.

---

`Parent
A
B
C (hover)
-> C1
-> C2
D(hover doesnt work the section gets closed.)
E`

Answer (score 0):

```
:host(:hover){
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
 }
```

In CSS file use this as a selector.You can even remove the (:hover) if doesn't want hover effect.

Comment: Hi Mehul..  I found that when the sub child is rendered.. I cant go below sections.. I suspect there is an overflow or height issues which prevents the hover on down elements